# How to make the dot.net core application show errors instead of emitting a blank 500 error page

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

This is the function that I have in my startup.cs.

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {

        app.UseCors(builder =>
        builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyOrigin());

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
              {
                  routes.MapRoute("apiActions", "api/{controller}/{action}");
              });


  app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
  app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();

  app.Use(async (context, next) =>
              {
                  await next();
                  if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 &&
                     !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value) &&
                     !context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api/"))
                  {
                      context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
                      await next();
                  }
              });
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();


  app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
        {
            // FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            // Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Images")),
            // RequestPath = new PathString("/Images")
        });
    }
```

What can I do to view an error in the response? I want the error to be emitted to the browser whenever I throw it in my controller.

So for example, if I do this:

```
    [HttpGet]
public string GetStartUpURL(string gameID, int userId, string mode)
{
  throw new Exception("Test");
 return null;
}
```

I want an error to be returned instead of a blank body response with 500 code.

I am using a web api core, not mvc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your issue, it is caused by that you are placing `Error Handling` before `UseMvc`. For catching error while this application, you should place `Error Handling Middleware` on the first.

Try to modify your `Configure` like below:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
  app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
  app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();

  app.Use(async (context, next) =>
              {
                  await next();
                  if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 &&
                     !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value) &&
                     !context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api/"))
                  {
                      context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
                      await next();
                  }
              });
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();


  app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
        {
            // FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            // Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Images")),
            // RequestPath = new PathString("/Images")
        });
app.UseCors(builder =>
        builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyOrigin());

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
              {
                  routes.MapRoute("apiActions", "api/{controller}/{action}");
              });
    }
```

If you want to custom the error reponse instead of using `UseDeveloperExceptionPage`. You could try something like below:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(
               new ExceptionHandlerOptions
               {
                   ExceptionHandler = async context =>
                   {
                       context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
                       var ex = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                       if (ex != null)
                       {
                           var err = $"<h1>Error: {ex.Error.Message}</h1>";
                           await context.Response.WriteAsync(err);
                       }
                   }
               });
```